# When using TAB completion with dd command, options (like 'if' or 'of') disappear

Tags: linux, bash, autocomplete, dd

When I type `dd if=` then hit **TAB** to complete, the file name is added, but the `if=` portion vanishes (and `of=` too, for that matter).

So for example, instead of

```
# dd if=input_file.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

I get

```
# dd input_file.iso /dev/sdb
```

when using **TAB** completion. What is going on?

Comment: Which shell are you using? Some of them are using dark magic these days... like bash tab completion helpers that just mess things up in completely unpredictable ways.

Comment: I'm using bash.

Comment: What version of bash are you using? How is completion defined for `dd`? (run `complete -p dd` to find out)

Comment: 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu), 'no completion specification'